# How to use cloud-init with debian Vagrant boxes?

Tags: debian, vagrant, cloud-init

It seems that `cloud-init` is not pre-installed in the `debian/bookworm64` Vagrant image as well as `debian/bullseye64`. I did not find any other relevant image in search. Is there a way to make cloud-init to execute the user script nonetheless, maybe with some local hacks?

Steps to reproduce:

- create a `Vagrantfile` using `vagrant init debian/bookworm64`
- follow [official steps](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/cloud-init/usage) to enable cloud-init (e.g. enable experimental features etc.) and add a section to `Vagrantfile`:

  ```
  config.vm.cloud_init :user_data do |cloud_init|
    cloud_init.content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    cloud_init.path = "userdata-local.yml"
  end
  ```
- create a simple `userdata-local.yml` file in the same directory e.g.

  ```
  runcmd:
    - echo "Hello world"
  ```

The end result of running `vagrant up` is the error `cloud-init is not found. Please ensure that cloud-init is installed and available on path for guest xyz`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the vagrant tag states: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did not find any other relevant image in search.

Consider using [cloud images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/) which have cloud-init pre-installed.

> Is there a way to make cloud-init to execute the user script nonetheless, maybe with some local hacks

If cloud-init is not installed, cloud-init certainly will not be running on your image on first boot.

What you could possibly do (if you would rather not use a cloud image) is install cloud-init after your image boots, then take a snapshot and use that as a base image to boot cloud-init instances from.

Comment: All right, I'm giving up on Debian and sticking with Ubuntu that has cloud-init